# Cake PHP 3 needs limit option for find all method

Tags: cakephp, orm, find, clause

Inside a cell I need to access the TreeOptions model.
So I've wrote this :

```
    $this->loadModel( 'TreeOptions' );

    $i = $this->TreeOptions->find( 'all' );
```

But when I do the foreach like this :

```
    foreach( $i as $row )
      debug( $row->description );
```

It only returns the last record of the result.
The only way I've found to make it work as desired is adding the limit clause :

```
     $i = $this->TreeOptions->find( 'all', [ 'limit' => 200 ] );
```

And then, I can get the whole set of records.
What am I missing ?

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first snippet, the variable `$i`, is a state where the query has not yet run. See the excerpt from [CakePHP 3 Cookbook: Retrieving Data & Results — Using Finders to Load Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data):

```
// Find all the articles.
// At this point the query has not run.
$query = $articles->find('all');

// Iteration will execute the query.
foreach ($query as $row) {
}

// Calling all() will execute the query
// and return the result set.
$results = $query->all();

// Once we have a result set we can get all the rows
$data = $results->toArray();

// Converting the query to an array will execute it.
$results = $query->toArray();
```