# Cakephp3 ElasticSearch Query Q

Tags: php, cakephp, elasticsearch, orm, cakephp-3.0

How do I make a query like

```
http://localhost:9200/index/businesses/_search?q=services
```

in Cakephp3 ElasticSearch

I have tried

```
$this->Businesses->find('all')->where(['*'=>'services']);
```

However I get no results.

Comment: TLDR; How do I search documents from ES datasource without specifying a column using CakephpES?

Answer (score 1):

The more accurate answer is to use a builder

```
    $q = 'services'; 
    $businesses = $this->Businesses->find('all')->where(function ($builder) use($q) {
            return $builder->query(new \Elastica\Query\SimpleQueryString($q));
        });
```

The _all key might solve the problem

```
$this->Businesses->find('all')->where(['_all'=>'services']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking, but the asterisk in `where(['*'=>'services'])` should be a column name in your table schema/database.

Another common issue is that the result of `find()` is not the result of the query by design. See my answer to [Cake PHP 3 needs limit option for find all method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086601/cake-php-3-needs-limit-option-for-find-all-method/36097091?noredirect=1#comment59846587_36097091) and also [CakePHP 3 Cookbook: ElasticSearch — Searching Indexed Documents](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/elasticsearch.html#searching-indexed-documents):

```
$query = $this->Articles->find()
    ->where([
        'title' => 'special',
        'or' => [
            'tags in' => ['cake', 'php'],
            'tags not in' => ['c#', 'java']
        ]
    ]);

// The query returns multiple rows which you can loop through
//  or alternatively you can call $query->all(); to get the object
//                                $query->toArray(); to get the array
foreach ($query as $article) {
    echo $article->title;
}
```

Comment: ElasticSearch allows you to search documents without specifying a column. I want to search without specifying a column.